# PhoneGap development roadblock: framework questions and opinions for a small CRM

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, angularjs, frameworks, cordova

I'm trying to achieve a relatively easy goal: create a simple cross-platform CRM app to manage contacts/customers and their relations with companies. At the current state I'm fairly confused on how to approach this (after some early motivational success).

After half a year of Objective-C and iOS development under my belt I wanted to get more serious and start on a real app project, which would be the mentioned CRM app. Then I heard about PhoneGap, tried it out and was very impressed. From there on it was clear to me that my app should be cross-platform.

To have a better understanding of what I'm trying to achieve, here are some details about the "requirements":

- Simple data model, 5 or 6 entities total. One-to-Many and Many-to-Many relationships.
- Have a tab-bar widget to quickly toggle between companies, clients, etc.
- search-as-you-type on listviews
- master-detail view behavior for listviews
- back buttons on the header, "add/edit" buttons as well. Classical app layout as you would expect.

My first steps lead me to JQuery Mobile for the UI which, at first glance, looked like the perfect candidate to quickly build a UI that fits the requirements and takes off a lot of coding from my hands. The mockup I created worked great on all devices, but then I hit a roadblock: the master=detail view navigation/routing. I had no clue how it's supposed to work and the JQuery Mobile docs don't supply an answer or best-practice for that. I figured out that I might be able to just pass an "id" in a querystring and read it on the details view. That worked to some extent, but only when the page is in an external file (detailsview.html?id=3) and not just an internal one (#detailsview?id=3). And even then I experienced some odd behavior when reading the value from the querystring on the pageshow event. Anyway, all this tinkering with logic and design led me to the clue that there must be a better and more organized approach, something like MVC. And apparently there is, namely backbone.js and Angular.js (and ember.js etc.) that come with decent deep-linking. Some googling told me that Angular.js might be a better fit for me since it comes with 2-way data-binding and makes me write less code, which is always appreciated.

But then there's the problem of a functional overlap between JQuery Mobile and Angular.js since JQuery Mobile has it's own routing capabilities. I could disable that part I guess, but I would probably lose the page transitions in the process (no more "pages" in the index.html)? I found topcoat as an alternative for the UI but it currently lacks a much needed/wanted tab-bar widget as it seems. Just as Twitter Bootstrap which seems to lack it as well.

And I haven't even touched persistent storage yet! The PhoneGap API provides storage capabilities but after some years with nice ORM implementations like Hibernate, Entity Framework and Core Data I want something more "natural" than pure SQL. On the other hand, pure SQL might be doable since the scope of the project is somewhat limited. So I came across JayData but have't tried it yet. Since Angular.js seems to prefer data input in JSON format, maybe Lawnchair.js might be a good idea? I looked into it but I couldn't quickly find out how to reference relations and/or objects in a traditional way. My learning curve aside, is lawnchair.js a good way at all to store relational data? Or CouchDB from a server perspective? Most of the examples I found only stored non-related data or contained arrays not referencing other objects. I guess all it needs is storing the object identifiers in those arrays, but how to do auto-create, auto-increment them and make sure that they're unique?

I would greatly appreciate your thoughts, comments and a little guidance on this :)!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would this perhaps not be more suitable for programmers.stackexchange?

Comment: You didn't really ask a question, just a whole bunch of thoughts. You will have much better results if you can extract some specific questions

Comment: Thanks guys! I looked into programmers.stackexchange and it seems like the more appropriate place for this type of thought output. I'll be more specific here in future questions and I'll answer my own question as the last weeks really helped me figure some things out. Maybe it will help someone else who comes along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the last weeks I was playing around with a bunch of storage and UI solutions, the ones that I settled with are lawnchair.js, JQuery Mobile and some other things like Handlebars.js for templating. They are fairly simple to use and exactly what I needed.

To store my JSONs I created Lawnchairs like this:

```
var clients = new Lawnchair({
name: 'clients'
}, function (store) {
// I don't really need the callback here
});
```

Lawnchair's JSON based storage makes it simple and intuitive to store your data directly in your javascript code with a single line:

```
clients.save({firstName: "Jason", lastName: "Bourne", ...});
```

This will also fully automagically create a unique key for you to access the object later. Big bonus that wasn't mentioned anywhere! You could create and define your own key, but for my purpose the auto-generated one fits perfect.

To create realtionships with your other Lawnchairs, like "companies", you could add the key to the querystring, read it on the detailspage, and add the key to the company's property you want, like:

```
myJSONclient = clients.get(SuperLongAutoGeneratedKeyReadFromAueryString);

// Probably do some stuff with the object

// Add the key to the current company object
currentCompany.bestCustomer = myJSONclient.key;

// save it
companies.save(currentCompany);
```

That's all there is to it :)!